# Month wise sales chart report using codeigniter mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I try to generate month wise sales chart report.[image]

Our month label is not a proper format.
i need label like this 
1st Month,2nd Month,3rd Month,4th Month,.......

Our mysql query

```
SELECT  concat('Month ' ,(@count:=@count+1)) as month,sum(grand_total) as amount FROM tra_inv_hd WHERE   fi_yr =1 group by MONTH(trninvhddt) order by trninvhddt asc
```

If..elseif condition used to change my query , finally i got result

```
SELECT if(MONTH(trninvhddt)=1,concat(MONTH(trninvhddt),'st Month'),if(MONTH(trninvhddt)=2,concat(MONTH(trninvhddt),'nd Month'),if(MONTH(trninvhddt)=3,concat(MONTH(trninvhddt),'rd Month'),concat(MONTH(trninvhddt),'th Month')))) as month,sum(grand_total) as amount FROM tra_inv_hd WHERE fi_yr =1 group by MONTH(trninvhddt) order by trninvhddt asc
```

Anyother way to generate query proper label format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get same result with CASE statement also like below.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(MONTH(trninvhddt), CASE
    WHEN MONTH(trninvhddt)%100 BETWEEN 11 AND 13 THEN "th Month"
    WHEN MONTH(trninvhddt)%10 = 1 THEN "st Month"
    WHEN MONTH(trninvhddt)%10 = 2 THEN "nd Month"
    WHEN MONTH(trninvhddt)%10 = 3 THEN "rd Month"
ELSE "th Month"
END) as month,sum(grand_total) as amount FROM tra_inv_hd WHERE fi_yr =1 group by MONTH(trninvhddt) order by trninvhddt asc
```